# Host Hugo on github

Tags: github, github-pages, hugo

I created a static website using Hugo and pushed the code on Github.

[Github Link](https://github.com/HunterJS-bit/massage-website)

So Now I have a problem with Hosting in on Github pages

When I enter my url from settings: https://hunterjs-bit.github.io/massage-website/

I get 404 not found

But If I use: https://hunterjs-bit.github.io/massage-website/public I get the correct URL,

How can I fix this so that my site is on the root and not in public ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set publishing source directory to `public/`:

1. In your repository go to the settings (click the cogwheel *Settings* tab under the line with your repo name)
2. Scroll down to the section *Github Pages*
3. Next to the selector with branch name which has folder icon and currently says **/ (root)** so change that to **/public** and click *Save* next to it.

This will redirect root `/` of your website to directory `public/` so that any files inside `public/` will be served as if they were directly in  `https://hunterjs-bit.github.io/massage-website/` root.

Official Github documentation: [Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)

Answer (score 0):

Push all files in the pubilc directory to the master branch of the Repository.(but the root directory)